# How to get average of last 5 value using groupby arraylist in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, arraylist, group-by, average

I am trying to group by arraylist and get average of last 5 items. please anyone suggest me i am stuck here

I done so far is this

```
aproxXInfos.groupBy { it.mac }
                .map { group ->
                    val beaconMac = group.key
                    val beaconAllValues = group.value
                    val averageRssi = beaconAllValues.sumBy { it.rssi } / beaconAllValues.size
                    println("Average rssi for beacon $beaconMac is $averageRssi")
                }
```

this is giving me the average from all values from a particular group but I only want is to get the average from the last 5 values.

I know i am almost there but i am stuck here

Any Help Would be Highly Appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `takeLast(n)` that will return a list with only the last `n` items. So in  your case:

```
val beaconAllValues = group.value.takeLast(5)
```

Comment: thank you i don't know the solution would be that easy

Comment: what if i have to take index in renge like count on base of 3 to 6 index value

Comment: You can use `.subList(fromIndex, toIndex)`